# Python attribute that is read only within class

Tags: python, attributes

I have a class:

```
class Portfolio:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class GenericStrategy:
    def __init__(self, portfolio: Portfolio):
        self.portfolio = portfolio

    def modify_ptf_value(new_value):
        self.portfolio.value = new_value
        # This should return an error
```

I'will write some strategies which will inherit from `GenericStrategy`. I'd like their methods to be able to read the attribute portfolio but not to modify it, nor its attributes.

I read something about the `@properties` decorator, but it only works if I don't want the attribute (and its attributes) to be accessible from the outside, i can still modify the attribute (and its attributes) from methods 'inside' the object.
Is there a way to make the attribute (and its attributes) 'read-only' except for the `__init__` method? Is my design wrong and should start over? I know it is up to the user not to modify "protected" attributes, but I would like to make it bullet proof. Any idea is well accepted, even if it requires a substantial change in the class design.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As opposed to other (commonly used) programming languages *Python* comes with a new approach regarding accessing class/instance members. For example, nothing is really private, the fields/methods that:

- start with an `_`, are regular fields
- start with `__` (and end with at most one `_`), are just name mangled, but they still can be accessed (even modified/deleted) from outside the class

So, at the end it's a matter of convention, and it relies that it will be followed by those who write code. Bottom line is there's **nothing** that would prevent an user gaining access to a class/instance's internals.

*Note*: In other language it's possible too to access private members: there are methods officially supported (like ***Reflection*** ([[Oracle]: Trail: The Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)) for *Java*), or not so officially supported (which require some "tricks" - e.g.: `reinterpret_cast`ing a `class` to a `struct` with the same structure for *C++*). Nowadays, more and more languages tend to offer a way to alter an instance structure.

Anyway, there is the so called ***Descriptor Protocol*** ([[Python]: Descriptor HowTo Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)) which is one of the *Python*'s most powerful (and also most misunderstood) features.

Using *descriptors* (as a side comment, *properties* rely on them), I wrote a piece of code that achieves (on some degree) what you're asking for:

```
class LockedAttribute(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
        self._set_count = 0
        self._set_treshold = 1

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        return instance.__dict__[self._name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if self._set_count >= self._set_treshold:
            raise AttributeError("Can't set attribute '{}'".format(self._name))
        else:
            instance.__dict__[self._name] = value
            self._set_count += 1

    def __delete__(self, instance):
        raise AttributeError("Can't delete attribute '{}'".format(self._name))


class GenericStrategy(object):
    portfolio = LockedAttribute("portfolio")

    def __init__(self, portfolio):
        self.portfolio = portfolio
        try:
            self.portfolio = portfolio
        except AttributeError as e:
            print("  ERROR: {}".format(e))

    def set_portfolio(self, new_value):
        self.portfolio = new_value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    strategy = GenericStrategy("some portfolio name")
    print("Portfolio: {}".format(strategy.portfolio))
    try:
        del strategy.portfolio
    except AttributeError as e:
        print("  ERROR: {}".format(e))
    try:
        strategy.set_portfolio("some 2nd portfolio name")
    except AttributeError as e:
        print("  ERROR: {}".format(e))
    try:
        strategy.portfolio = "some 3rd portfolio name"
    except AttributeError as e:
        print("  ERROR: {}".format(e))
    print("Portfolio: {}".format(strategy.portfolio))
```

**Notes**:

- I removed `__` from the private attribute's name (`portfolio`) to avoid using the mangling that I was talking about, in my code (would make it more difficult to read)
- For *Py27* compatibility, the classes inherit `object`. If the compatibility isn't mandatory, the inheritance relation can be deleted (in *Py3x* it is by default)
- I added the `try/except` blocks to illustrate the behavior, in *production* they should be deleted
- As I stated above, if anyone wants to alter this behavior, **can**

Comment: This way the whole object portfolio cannot be changed, but I can still change attributes of the object portfolio. I edited the question to make it clearer. Descriptors seem like a great thing, I need to learn how they work.

Comment: Hmm, I was afraid that this would be the next question. The general answer is that you **can't** make them **truly** _bullet proof_. A consumer of your class/instance will be able to play with them. Regarding the question itself, I don't have an answer. An alternative would be to make the `portfolio` type objects use `LockedAttribute` as well, and make them _read-only_ (,or initialize them in `GenericStrategy.__init__` - which would break any aggregation), but I doubt that this would fit your needs.

Comment: I felt like it was impossible... Thanks for the answer anyway, the locked attribute class is great

Comment: Thank you. You can take a look at [\[Python\]: abc module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html), or [\[Python\]: `__setattr__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__), maybe you could something from there to get you closer to your goal.